# SQL Alchemy - Python script to migrate from Oracle to MySQL

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, etl, cx-oracle, pymysql

I'm trying to perform bulk extracts/loads from Oracle to MySQL using cx_Oracle and SQL Alchemy.

I found this example online and it works well for most data types, but fails from Blob data types:

https://vbaoverall.com/transfer-data-from-oracle-to-mysql-using-sqlalchemy-python/

I have about 43 tables and about 12 of them have `BLOB` data types.

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# list out all 43 tables:
table_list = [
    "FILE",
    "ATTACHMENT",
    "DOCUMENTS",
    "USERS",
    "INFO",
    "ONE",
    "TWO",
    "THREE",
    "FOUR",
    "...."
]

# Set Oralce Connection
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('source.example.com', '1530', service_name='test')
oracle_connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user='root', password='toot', dsn=dsn_tns)

# Open Oracle cursor
cursor = oracle_connection.cursor()

# set mysql connection with foreign key checks
mysql_engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:toot@target.example.com:3306/target")
mysql_engine.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0")

# loop thru tables:
for table in table_list:

    # select from oracle
    sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table

    # read into pandas df
    data=pd.read_sql(sql, oracle_connection)

    # insert into mysql
    mysql_engine.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE "+table)
    data.to_sql(table, con=mysql_engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000)
    print("{}: sucessfully inserted {} rows.".format(table, data.shape[0]))

# update foreign key checks
mysql_engine.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1")

#close connection
oracle_connection.close()
mysql_engine.dispose()
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
return "'%s'" % escape_string(str(value), mapping)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type bytes)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `dtype=` argument to `to_sql()` to explicitly set the column type?

Comment: I received a different error when trying this out:

`dtype = {}
 dtype['FILE_CONTENT'] = sqlalchemy.types.BLOB`

I tried both `BLOB` and `BINARY` and received this error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) cannot convert 'cx_Oracle.LOB' object to bytes`

Comment: Actually, it worked when I changed type to `PickleType`. Thank you @GordThompson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Gord Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144390/gord-thompson), I found out I just needed to specify `dtype=`

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlalchemy
import pymysql
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

table_list = [
    "FILE",
    "ATTACHMENT",
    "DOCUMENTS",
    "USERS",
    "INFO",
    "ONE",
    "TWO",
    "THREE",
    "FOUR",
    "...."
]

# Set Oralce Connection
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('source.example.com', '1530', service_name='test')
oracle_connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user='root', password='toot', dsn=dsn_tns)

# Open Oracle cursor
cursor = oracle_connection.cursor()

# set mysql connection with foreign key checks
mysql_engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:toot@target.example.com:3306/target")
mysql_engine.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0")

for table in table_list:

    # select from oracle
    sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table

    # read into pandas df
    data=pd.read_sql(sql, oracle_connection)

    dtype = {}
    if table == "ATTACHMENT":
        dtype['FILE_CONTENT'] = sqlalchemy.types.PickleType

    # insert into mysql
    mysql_engine.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE "+table)
    data.to_sql(table, con=mysql_engine, if_exists='append', index = False, chunksize =10000, dtype=dtype)
    print("{}: sucessfully inserted {} rows.".format(table, data.shape[0]))

# update foreign key checks
mysql_engine.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1")

#close connection
oracle_connection.close()
mysql_engine.dispose()
```